# 18.04 texlive-full install fail

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, latex

Looks like I'm not the only one having this problem. I have not found any work-around.

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

which produces the following,

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-full : Depends: asymptote but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: cm-super (>= 0.3.3-3) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: context but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: dvipng but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: feynmf but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: fragmaster but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: latex-cjk-all (>= 4.6.0+cvs20060714-2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: latexmk but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: prerex (> 6.5.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: purifyeps but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-base (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-bibtex-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2017.20170524.44437)
            Depends: texlive-extra-utils (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-font-utils (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-fonts-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-fonts-extra-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-formats-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-games (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-humanities (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-humanities-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-arabic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-chinese (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-cjk (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-cyrillic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-czechslovak (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-english (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-european (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-french (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-german (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-greek (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-italian (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-japanese (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-korean (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-other (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-polish (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-portuguese (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-lang-spanish (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-base-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-extra-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-latex-recommended-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-luatex (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-metapost (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-metapost-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-music (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-pictures (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-pictures-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-pstricks (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-pstricks-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-publishers (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-publishers-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-science (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-science-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: texlive-xetex (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: tipa (>= 2:1.2-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: vprerex (> 6.5.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)